# Converting an array into individual URLs - Currently done via line breaks, can I do it by special characters also?

Tags: php

This is the operational part of my code:

```
$drivers = explode("\r\n", $value );

$value = '';
foreach ($drivers as $dr){
    $value .= '<a href="/driver.php?q='. $dr . '~Driver">'. $dr . '</a><br>';
}
```

The entry in my database is simply a list.

*Item1

Item2

Item3

etc.*

The code above converts each one into a URL, which then comes out as "www.myurl.com/driver.php?q=Item1"

However, some of the items in this column are written as:

*Item4/Item5

Item 6*

Of course this means the generated URL is "www.myurl.com/driver.php?q=Item4/Item5". I would like the / to be seen the same way as a line break so Item4 and Item5 are clickable individually when separated by a /, while retaining the original functionality with the line breaks.

Is this possible?

Comment: use preg_split instead, which allows regexes.

Comment: You could simply `str_replace('/', "\r\n", $value)` before exploding.

Comment: mister martin, this works perfectly well, but then it also alters the formatting of the entries. I still want to retain the Item1/Item2 format :-) I will try some of the others, but this is a nice stopgap solution, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood the question well, you want to show `a/b` links as separate links, with the inner text of `a` and `b`, respectively, pointing to the page `a/b`. If I am right, this should be the solution:

```
$drivers = explode("\r\n", $value );

$value = '';
foreach ($drivers as $dr){
    $elements = ((strpos($dr, "/") === false) ? array(0 => $dr) : (explode("/", $dr)));
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $value .= '<a href="/driver.php?q='. $dr . '~Driver">'. $element . '</a><br>';
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
$drivers = explode("\r\n", $value );

$value = '';
foreach ($drivers as $dr){
    $elements = ((strpos($dr, "/") === false) ? array(0 => $dr) : (explode("/", $dr)));
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $value .= (($index++ === 0) ? '' : '/') . '<a href="/driver.php?q='. $element . '~Driver">'. $element . '</a>' .'<br>';
    }
}
```

The above untested code attempts to be closer to the real needs.

EDIT2:

```
$drivers = explode("\r\n", $value );

$value = '';
foreach ($drivers as $dr){
    $elements = ((strpos($dr, "/") === false) ? array(0 => $dr) : (explode("/", $dr)));
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $value .= (($index++ === 0) ? '' : '/') . '<a href="/driver.php?q='. $element . '~Driver">'. $element . '</a>';
    }
    $value .= '<br>';
}
```

Comment: It's actually the other way around. Currently a/b is the link I'm getting, but I would like the inner text to be two separate URLs, with the forward slash being the character which delineates them. So 'a' should have its own URL and so should 'b'. However I just tested this and it works as you said, and may be useful for other things, so thank you!

Comment: @user1708538, you are welcome, but I did not give up answering your question. I have edited my answer and I hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Yes! We are so nearly there, this is almost perfect! The ONLY issue I'm having now is an extra line break has crept in before the forward slash. Is there a way to ignore this? I still want the line break after a/b, and I also want it after other entries, such as where 'c' is on its own, and 'd' is on its own. Currently it's basically acting like `a<br>/b', if that makes sense.

Comment: @user1708538, thank you for pointing that out. I have edited my answer and hope it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions to the rescue!

```
$drivers = preg_split('/[\n|\/]/', $value );

$value = '';
foreach ($drivers as $dr){
    $dr = trim($dr);
    if($dr) $value .= '<a href="/driver.php?q='. urlencode($dr) . '~Driver">'. htmlspecialchars($dr, ENT_QUOTES) . '</a><br>';
}
```

[`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is invaluable for parsing user input.  This regular expression splits on `newline` and `/`.  I trimmed the result and added a condition so that extra space and empty lines are ignored.

I've also added [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to help keep your page display from breaking if you have unexpected characters.

Note, I used your code example rather than your explanation for the url builder. Small discrepancy there.

Comment: This has had an interesting effect. All the drivers called 'Richard' or 'Robert' are now called 'ichard' and 'obert'. It has also removed all my French and German names, like François and Müller.

Comment: Interesting.  The `\R` is probably the culprit for your first issue.  I'll test and update.  Not sure about the special characters.  Let me look around.  Edit: what character encoding are you using?

Comment: I'm not having that trouble with the special characters in my test environment.  Are you sure you're reading your data in with the correct character encoding?  Also, do a `print_r($drivers)` to see if the values make it into the array after the split.

Comment: Another user above has solved my issue. But to answer your question, I am using UTF8_bin I think.